# Getting values ​using AsyncTask

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask

I have some error, so I need help.

I want to input the value using EditText in MainThread, and save the file according to the name using AsyncTask parameter. The file is created well, but with a strange name.(Passtext has no problems.)

-MainThread

```
CheckTypesTask typesTask=new CheckTypesTask();
String Passtext=SaveFileName.getText().toString();
typesTask.execute(Passtext);
```

-AsyncTask

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... ReceivedFileName) {
        String ReceivedFileNameToString=ReceivedFileName.toString();
        Log.e("ReceivedFileNameToStirng",ReceivedFileNameToString);
```

-Log.e

```
E/ReceivedFileNameToStirng: [Ljava.lang.String;@e7754ca
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method parameter

```
String... ReceivedFileName
```

it's not a String, it's called varargs so to get your fileName you need to get the first string on the ReceivedFileName, you can deal with it as an array

```
String ReceivedFileNameToString = ReceivedFileName[0];
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try it. And so sorry about answer to late.